# MAX809S not working with a voltage divider on input

Tags: voltage, integrated-circuit, reset, 24v, supervisor

I am trying to get a MAX809S IC to work with a 24 V supply. The MAX should trigger at around 2.93 V at its VCC pin and turn the RESET pin high. Because the MAX is only rated at max. 6 V at the VCC pin I created a voltage divider with a 2k and 510Ω resistor. Sadly the MAX is not switching the RESET pin. It is working perfectly fine if i provide a 0-5 V supply directly to the VCC pin. The voltage divider is capable of delivering almost 10 mA. This should be more than enough to power it. What am I doing wrong? The MAX should turn on/off at around 15V but it does nothing. I can not lower the resistor values anymore because they will overheat then. [image]

Comment: Please add a link to the device's data sheet.

Comment: I found a datasheet [MAX803-MAX810Z.pdf](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/MAX803-MAX810Z.pdf). Maximum supply current is shown as 100 µA.

Comment: I am referring to this datasheet: https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/max809s-d.pdf
There it says maximum input current 20mA and supply current max 2.5µA

Comment: Remove C2 and R3 and just measure the voltage on pin 2.

Comment: Which MAX809S are you using?  These are available in a number of reset thresholds

Comment: I tried the 809STR (2.93V) and 809TTR (3.08V). But my STR board had the capacitors soldered on and i did not expect them to cause a problem. The TTR (without any caps) resolved the problem

Comment: @SpehroPefhany - Hi, FYI your suggestion allowed the problem to be identified, if you want to write an answer on that.

Comment: If @SpehroPefhany wants to write an answer i will accept it as the solution. Feel free to do so

Comment: Are you ok with burning 230 mW continuously? Seems excessive.

Comment: No, that was only for testing because i thought the MAX needs more current for some reason. As i said in my answer i swapped the resistors with a 50k pot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thx @Spehro Pefhany. It was in fact the 47nF (C2) capacitor that caused the problem. I dont know exactly why but at least it is working now. C1 or R3 did not cause any problems.

EDIT: I also changed R1 and R2 to a 50k potentiometer which also works. With a 100k potentiometer it stopped working though.

Comment: FullMetalJack - Hi, Just a bit of feedback: While you *can* write (and, after 48 hrs, áccept) your own answer, you found the solution through a comment from someone else, so it would be polite to first reply *in a comment* to that person, inviting *them* to write an answer. || You seem to have tried to reply in an answer using `@username` but *that only triggers a notification from a comment* since answers are not supposed to address *people*, but just to be *the solution*. || I will add a comment and invite that user to write an answer (it's their choice whether or not to do so). Thanks.